# I can't connect to any wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I've just had a burned router. When I now try to connect my PC to the new one (Dlink wireless AC750 DIR-810L) that is set to default settings except I've tried several different channels, default settings is set to run all bands a/b/g/n.

My Sony xperia, an iphone and an ipad can connect without problems.

My PC can connect from Ubuntu (i have dual-boot) but not from the Win7 section. It finds the networks, i type password, but it just gets me the "cant connect to wireless network" message.

I get the same when i try to connect my PC to the hotspot on my xperia.

Ideas?

Comment: Silly question, but is the password typed correctly? What about if you remove the password from the network?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that the drivers for Win7 are up-to-date. Old drivers may be lacking WPA/WPA2 support, or incomplete AES/TKIP implementations. However, it may very well be that the available Windows drivers are just unmaintained and are no longer supported. Linux-based drivers are typically built on common frameworks and reverse engineered, so they are maintained by the wifi team, rather than the manufacturer themselves.

Alternatively, you can try reducing the security on your wifi, as long as you're also aware that anything under WPA2 is trivially broken. WPA2 is breakable, too, but is at least more resilient than its predecessors.